# Parsing comma separated variables in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, csv

I'm trying to write a function that reads a csv file and returns the contents, I thought the solution would just be a simple 2-dimensional array but the only information I can find is that not only is this frowned upon but also the only way of returning a 2-dimensional (or more) array from a C++ function involves predetermining the size.

I don't like the idea of pre-defining my array size as in this particular context I would need an array set up to hold 256TiB of data as I can't know the file size before reading it.

What I want to know is what is the *correct* way of doing this?

Comment: Look up [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: Do some more research, CSV parsing questions come up daily here. That said, handling 256TiB of data is not going to be easy anyway, you will have to make the code scalable.

Comment: That was my point, to make the code scalable. All I know about the file before reading it into a variable is that it is less than the theoretical maximum which in the current context is 256TiB.

I have been researching this on and off for 2 weeks before asking this, I have not yet seen a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The details would depend on exactly what you are doing but a common solution would be to have a `std::vector` of a `struct` (which holds the fields):

```
// the CSV fields will be read into the struct's data members
struct record
{
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
    unsigned age;
    // ...
};

std::vector<record> read_csv(std::istream& is)
{
    std::vector<record> records;

    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(is, line))
    {
        record r;
        // populate r with CSV data in line
        records.push_back(r); // add record to vector
    }

    return records;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for one dimension. Currently I'm trying to figure out how to use push_back if I'm using a 2D vector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list array of list array.

Read a line, split, create a list array.

Add this list array to the list array of rows, let say the cvs list array.

You will be able to access the element with csv[row][column]

cvs.count() is the number of rows, cvs[row].count() is the number of elemets in the row.

Easy... Good luck!